# Deleting a child Item in Nested Recyclerview caused jumping animation effect

Tags: android, android-layout, kotlin, android-recyclerview

i have a question about a recyclerview. So i have a nested recyclerview , When i delete the child item i'm using this scenario

1. childAdapter.notifyItemdeleted(position)
2. parentAdapter.notifyItemChanged(parentPosition)

I have to do the 2nd step to prevent a white/blank space between the parent item. But it has another side effect which look like this :

[image: Jumping Animation]

as you can see, the recyclerview is jumping /scrolling to the parent item

Comment: Can you please share your adapter's code?

Comment: which part of the code ? whole adapter class?

Comment: The `RecyclerView.Adapter` class and the code where you delete your list items

Comment: Adapter https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/690239808479821847/817098123360337990/unknown.png